# checking for spaces with c++

Tags: c++, string, stl

So I've looked around the site for someone having a similar issue but nothing has come up and it's really been perplexing me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string reverse(string s)
{
    int start = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==' '){
            string new_word = s.substr(start,i);
            cout << new_word << endl;
            start = i+1;
         }   
    }
    return "hi";
}



int main(){
    cout << reverse("Hey there my name is am");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the tidbit of code above this is what I get as an output.

```
Hey
there my 
my name is
name is am
is am
hi
```

as you can see the if condition doesn't seem to break on every space. I have also tried isspace(s[i]) and that produced the same result as above. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the if condition is getting skipped on certain white spaces and not others. Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: You really have to work on making your indentation line up. Keeping your code clean and organized is extremely important, *especially* when asking for help.

Comment: This would be a good time to use a debugger to step through your code and discover which part is behaving unexpectedly.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: Perhaps the [documentation on substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) will help

Comment: @tadman I updated the code, my mistake.

Comment: Looking good now.

Comment: @Kevin that did help, I misread it originally. Thanks! For those wondering the issue was not with isspace() or my if but I was cutting the substring in the wrong spot.

Comment: Hint: Read up on [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) more carefully, pay attention to what the second argument should be.

Comment: @sf8193 Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Tyger yes I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the reference of [string::substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/). It clearly states that `len` takes the **number of characters** to include in the substring. In your code you are passing the index of `' '` which is simply wrong because it does not correspond to `len`. Instead of using `s.substr(start,i)`, simply use `s.substr(start,i - start + 1)`. That should fix the problem.